# cannot resolve symbol setOnPageChangeListener

Tags: java, android, android-fragmentactivity

I Couldnot find any relevant solution for My Scenario.I am working on select the respected tab manually on Tab Swipe..I am  learning from

http://www.androidgreeve.com/2014/01/android-actionbar-navigating-with-swipeable-tabs-and-views.html

In MainActivity ,on Adding viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener it doesnot recognizes it ..it thows error ...

```
cannot resolve symbol setOnPageChangeListener
```

Here is the code

```
package com.example.administrator.fragmentsexample;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.example.administrator.adapter.TabsPagerAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = {"Social", "Organizer", "Movies"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initilization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {

    }

    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // on changing the page
            // make respected tab selected
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });

}
```

What I am missing ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to move this:

```
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        // on changing the page
        // make respected tab selected
        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
    }
});
```

into onCreate. I think current placement of the call does not make sense. :-)